# How to preserve file mode attributes with CP in Windows 10 command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I have a build script failing on Windows 10 because copied files are becoming read-only and a perl script cannot open them.

The same is passing fine on Windows XP and Windows 7.

To validate the cp operation on its own:

- The source file is a txt file.
- With a perl script using stat, I see the source file mode is 666.
- I copy the file with `cp` in a Windows 10 command prompt.

  ```
  cp -p c:\data\salt.txt c:\download\salt.txt
  ```
- In the destination folder, the file mode is now 444, and the perl script cannot open the file.
- Using `chmod`, I can change the mode from 444 to 666, but the perl script still cannot open the file.
- Using either `-p` or `--preserve=mode` doesn't seem to change the outcome of the `cp` operation.

If I use `xcopy` or `robocopy` the destination file retains its 666 mode and all is good.
But I would like to figure out why the `cp` command is not working.

I have admin privileges on the PC and full control on the c:\ drive and all its sub folders.

I have tried in a normal command prompt and in a prompt run as administrator but the failure is the same in both.

Comment: You should ask this on superuser.com, and include the source of these `cp` and `chmod` commands. Are they MSYS, Cygwin or something else? They can't be from the new Linux subsystem, since that would require paths such as "/mnt/c/data/salt.txt".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will look on superuser.com.
The cp and chmod commands are what is available in the Windows 10 command prompt. I don't think I can find the source code for these though.

Comment: @MaximeFortin there's no cp and chmod in Windows 10 cmd. There's cp which is an alias of Copy-Item in powershell but no chmod. Run `where cp` and `where chmod` to see

Comment: In particular, there are no cp.exe and chmod.exe programs distributed with Windows; common sources for these Unix command-line programs include Cygwin and the MSYS bash environment (e.g. as distributed with Git). Windows comes with xcopy.exe and robocopy.exe for copying files; attrib.exe for modifying file attributes; and icacls.exe for modifying file security. The CMD shell has `copy` and `move` built-in commands. PowerShell has `Copy-Item`; `Get-Item` for a file's `Attributes` property; and `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` for security.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc
Yes, I stand corrected, sorry for my mistake.
The locations of these are in cygwin\bin on my PC